# AWS 1 VPC for 2 EC2 Instances, 1 of which is an OpenVPN server for which the other needs to connect to

Tags: ubuntu, python, openvpn, aws, amazon-ec2

As described in the title, how can I connect my OpenVPN server to another running EC2 instance (Both operating in the same region and VPC) such that all API commands sent through the running EC2 instance are done so using the VPN connection?

-Would I need to ensure that they both have the same elastic IP?
-Should they be on the same Subnet as well as VPC?
-For the addressing method (setting on VPN) do I select routing or NAT?
-Could I configure my VPN as a gateway?